# Blank page while trying to crawl angularjs based websites

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to crawl a website that is using angularjs, but when I tried to open, it always give blank page.

For example,the main website of angularjs - https://angularjs.org/
Here is the code I am writing -

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = {width: 1280, height: 1024};
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36';
page.settings.javascriptEnabled = true;

page.open('https://angularjs.org/', function(status) {
            if(status == 'success') {
                console.log("hello");
                page.render('web.png');
        phantom.exit();
            }
            else {
                console.log("error opening page");
                phantom.exit();
            }

});
```

Comment: Is the console saying `hello` or `error opening page`? Have you tried other, non-angularjs pages that worked?

Comment: Your script worked fine for me (I successfully got a web.png containing the full contents of the Angularjs homepage.)

Comment: bootstrap may be the answer you were looking for

Comment: @jonhopkins:- yes I have tried non-angular pages...

Comment: @DanielBeck:- Did you get the screenshot with same code. Also let me know the version of phantomjs you are trying with.

Comment: @Asqan:- Please elaborate

Comment: I used phantomjs 2.1.1, and yes, did get the screenshot.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: @DanielBeck:- Thanks..:)
I was using phantom 1.9.8 . I upgraded it and things worked..:)